# Disable jQueryUI datepicker dates based on Select value change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When a value is selected from a SELECT list, an existing empty array `var disableddates = [];` gets populated with a list of dates in a '2016-03-21' format.

I want a jquery UI datepicker to disable the dates from within the array following the event but it simply does not work.

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        // rest of the code

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
```

When I set `disableddates` with a specific date or multiple dates before the code runs, it actually gets disabled so the only problem here is that I can't get datepicker to disable dates on events as mentioned above.

Also, if I use the event `beforeShow` instead of `beforeShowDay`, nothing happens.

A `console.log` confirms that the array is indeed getting populated so I'm sure it's just an issue with the way datepicker's event works.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a rather simple solution. I called refresh method on the datepicker after the array is populated, every time.

```
$.each(data.response, function(i, item) {
    disableddates.push(item);
});

// end array population

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
```